# JAVA illegal start of expresion

Tags: java, netbeans

quisiera saber si  me pueden ayudar con un error que me sale al querer ejecutar un código en java. La verdad que hace tiempo no programo y no se por qué me da error el código. El error que me bota es

> illegal start of expresion en la línea de código 89

(la que cierra el primer método).

Saludos y gracias

```
 public class CaminosMinimos {

//Determinar caminos
public String algoritmoFloyd(long[][] mAdy) {

    int vertices = mAdy.length;
    long matrizAdyacencia[][] = mAdy;
    String caminos[][] = new String[vertices][vertices];
    String caminosAuxiliares[][] = new String[vertices][vertices];
    String caminoRecorrido = "", cadena = "", caminitos = "";
    int i, j, k;
    float temporal1, temporal2, temporal3, temporal4, minimo;
    //iniciar las matrices caminos y caminos auxiliares

    for (i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < vertices; j++) {
            caminos[i][j] = "";
            caminosAuxiliares[i][j] = "";
        }
    }
    for (k = 0; k < vertices; k++) {
        for (i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < vertices; j++) {

                temporal1 = matrizAdyacencia[i][j];
                temporal2 = matrizAdyacencia[i][k];
                temporal3 = matrizAdyacencia[k][j];
                temporal4 = temporal2 + temporal3;
                //encontrar minimo

                minimo = Math.min(temporal1, temporal4);
                if (temporal1 != temporal4) {
                    if (minimo == temporal4) {
                        caminoRecorrido = "";
                        caminosAuxiliares[i][j] = k + "";
                        caminos[i][j] = caminosR(i, k, caminosAuxiliares, caminoRecorrido) + (k + 1);

                    }
                }
                matrizAdyacencia[i][j] = (long) minimo;

            }
        }
    }
    //Agregando el camino minimo a cadena

    for (i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < vertices; j++) {

            cadena = cadena + "[" + matrizAdyacencia[i][j] + "]";
        }

        cadena = cadena + "/n";
    }
    //////////////////LÓGICA DEL ALGORITMO

    for (i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < vertices; j++) {
            if (matrizAdyacencia[i][j] != 1000000000) {
                if (i != j) {
                    if (caminos[i][j].equals("")) {

                        caminitos += "De (" + (i + 1) + " ---> " + (j + 1) + ") Irse Por ...(" + (i + 1) + " ," + (j + 1) + ") \n";
                    } else {

                        caminitos += "De (" + (i + 1) + " ---> " + (j + 1) + ") Irse Por ...(" + (i + 1) + " ," + caminos[i][j] + "," + (j + 1) + ") \n";
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }

    return "La matriz de caminos más cortos entre los diferentes vértices es: \n" + cadena
            + "\n los diferentes caminos más cortoes entre vertices son \n" + caminitos +
            
            
            }

public String caminosR(int i, int k, String[][] caminosAuxiliares, String caminoRecorrido) {
    if (caminosAuxiliares[i][k].equals("")) {

        return "";
    } else {
        //Recursividad al millon

        caminoRecorrido += caminosR(i, Integer.parseInt(caminosAuxiliares[i][k].toString()),
                caminosAuxiliares, caminoRecorrido) + Integer.parseInt(caminosAuxiliares[i][k].toString() + 1) + ",";

        return caminoRecorrido;
    }
} 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> "Illegal start of expression"

En este caso marca el error en el `}` de cierre pero el problema es causado por la linea de código anterior, el final de esta linea de código es el problema:

```
return "La matriz de caminos más cortos entre los diferentes vértices es: \n" + cadena
        + "\n los diferentes caminos más cortoes entre vertices son \n" + caminitos +
```

Tienes un signo `+` al final y no estas concatenando nada, simplemente termina la linea con `;`

```
return "La matriz de caminos más cortos entre los diferentes vértices es: \n" + cadena
        + "\n los diferentes caminos más cortoes entre vertices son \n" + caminitos;
```

Comment: jajaja , muchas gracias :)

Comment: Imagino funciono verdad? Recuerdo que a mi me sucedia, no encontraba el problema pero al final notaba que se encontraba en la línea anterior. =)

Comment: Si funcionó , ni siquiera había visto esa línea , ahora miraré una por una jaja , gracias :)